# What is optimize way to passing data to queue as a chunk of hundred?

Tags: php, laravel

how to optimize this using queue in laravel.
i have controller when i call route it start inserting data in database using queue.
The Inserting function present in queue and i want to insert data in chunk with delay of 30 seconds.

```
for($i=1; $i<=400;$i++)
{
$data = ['name'=> 'Walter Zada','email' => 'walterworld@gmail.com'];
if($i<=100)
InsertJOb::dispatch($data);//->delay(now()->addSeconds(15));
else if($i>100 && $i<=200)
{
InsertJOb::dispatch($data)->delay(now()->addSeconds(20));
}
else if($i>200 && $i<=300)
{
InsertJOb::dispatch($data)->delay(now()->addSeconds(20));
}
else if($i>300 && $i<=400)
{
InsertJOb::dispatch($data)->delay(now()->addSeconds(20));
}           
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Imagine having data in one big array instead of generating like you do. If you want you can generate it to an array.

So data would look like so.

```
[['name'=> 'Walter Zada','email' => 'walterworld@gmail.com'], ...];
```

Now you can clean up the code and use `Laravels` `chunk()` method for this data approach.

```
$data = collect($yourDate);
$now = now();

$data->chunk(100)->each(function (array $chunkedData) use ($now) {
    InsertJob::dispatch($chunkedData)->delay($now->addSeconds(20));
});
```

Comment: its show me undefined $data in dispatch while i assign data to $data.

Comment: Sorry you should pass chunkedData :)

Comment: Did it help your problem?

Comment: Thankyou its help alot

Comment: how i am not very much familiar with stackoverflow.

Comment: There is a check marker next to my answer, then you can mark it as answered and the question will be known to have been answered. That is the common approach, when people have helped you and you solved it.